# porting iPad app to iPhone using one storyboard with one storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, storyboard

i am able to make my iPad app running on iPhone but the iPhone screens doesnt fit all the content in. For example my table view main text is hidden, the buttons are very much spaced from the border. I understand the spacing given in my storyboard files in too big for iPhone screen.

I want to make my app work for iPhone with very minimal changes. I dont want to create a new storyboard and rewrite everything. Please suggest a good way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: yes, i am using autolayout. the border spacing works fine. the spacing between each label doesnt auto resize. for example i have a space of 200px from my table view to button. This looks good on iPad. But on iPhone button is not visible at all.

Comment: Have you followed any tutorials? I found this one to be really helpful to get started: http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the app Universal, make a single storyboard the main storyboard in both target's project settings and use [Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) to position your UI elements respective of the device. Look into [Size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html) to keep your design responsive.

Comment: i am using storyboard and auto layout. But not size classess. Is there way to achieve this without size classes?

Comment: Yes it is possible to do, but you would need to probably add extra constraints and control these in code. It will be much easier to just use size classes.

Comment: I have started using size classes. I set Regular Height and Compact width constraints for iPhone. But these are appearing on iPad 7.9'',9.7''.